# session[:key] = value doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make use of session data in my application and for some reason I don't have something setup right.

The code:

```
session[:key] = some_value
```

Generates the following error:

```
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

Other controllers don't have an issue with the session, so I am guessing I missed some basic configuration thing somewhere.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code that's generating the error. You say 'other controllers' without indicating what controller this line is in and how it's configured.

Comment: I jumped the gun a bit.  The real issue is that there is a post method being called from javascript and in that method, the session is not valid.

Comment: The plot thickens even more.  This is only happening in Chrome, works fine in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it figured out now.  I had a slightly more complex situation that my example.  I actually had the following:

```
session[:chat_history][chat.from.id] ||= []
```

So I had an error with double array.  I added the following:

```
session[:chat_history] ||= []
```

Problem was the first time I did this, I put it in a before_filter method.  Apparently the session object is nil in the before_filter method, at least the way I have my application setup.

So I moved the initializer to the methods that actually access the session and life is good again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the session variable is nil which makes me think the framework couldn't set it for one of these reasons:

1. Browser passed in no cookie for the session
2. Browser passed in a cookie but it didn't match anything the server expected

It was stated that some controllers work. Did something have the opportunity to create a session for the user before those controllers ran?

Comment: See my comments on original post